# External monitor not responding

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, display, integrated-graphics

I'm connecting my laptop through a docking station to an external monitor.

When I open a Chrome browser window in external monitor and try to scroll, nothing seems to happen. When I move the window back to my laptop's native monitor the scroll actually did happen. So it's just the external monitor that is not responding.

What could be the problem and how can I troubleshoot this?

I have [ThinkPad X1 Carbon](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tech-specs/laptop/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/)  (Intel® HD Graphics 4000(integrated))

Connecting to [UltraSharp U2421](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Displays/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&sku=320-2676)

Trough [ThinkPad USB 3.0 Dock station](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=460&Code=0A33970)